# php's echo 'n' space in href link

Tags: php, html, url

I used PHP's echo string in the WhatsApp share link, but when I share it on WhatsApp, the title space separates the trailing characters. help me.

```
<a class="footerbtn" href="whatsapp://send?text= *Surinder Muni* Early To Bed & Early To Rise* %0Amysite.com/?n=Good Morning">
```

```
<?php
      echo $GET['n']
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Before we code, we need to first learn how to format our code :). Let's format the codes properly before the rest help you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to encode space (and other potencial invalid characters) when create link in WhatsApp

```
echo urlencode('Good morning');
```

In PHP for reading the `$_GET['n']` value will be

```
echo urldecode($_GET['n']);
```